# can i hide the records in a record type so that only system admin can see them?

Tags: trigger

can i hide the records in a record type so that only system admin can see them?
 I want to hide products archive record type where I can put the products that has checkbox value false. ( I dont wish to delete it because if the checkbox is set to true, It will be transferred to another record type so that it will be available again. Is this possible? what approach can i use?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the sharing rules and groups or roles to achieve this. If access is limited to only specific roles, use that. Otherwise, create a group of the users who can access those records.

For the sharing part, make the criteria of Record Type = (Desired Record Type)

Then, just make that shared with the group or role.

Keep in mind that any profile that is set to View All for that object will be able to see all of those records, regardless of sharing rules.

Comment: I have no products sharing rule.. where can i possibly create my sharing rules for the record type of a product

Comment: I apologize. I apparently cannot read, as I did not realize that this was for the Product Object. Currently, there are no sharing rules available for Product. There is a request for Salesforce to add this, but that request has been there for a while. https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bp8V  I am going to suggest that you uncheck the answer if you can.